# Htaccess redirects not working from sub-subfolder to rootfile

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I am trying to redirect some pages from an old website to a new one. Redirects like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?de-tafels/(.*)$ /meubels/woonkamer/tafels$1 [R,L]
```

are working, but redirects from sub/subfolders to a file in the root directory are not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/?fotogalerij/hekwerken/(.*)$ /404$1 [R,L]
```

Should I add something behind the 404$1?

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/woonbeurs-a-dam-2010/(.*)$ /404$1 [R,L]
```

With this line I would like to redirect 
http://example.com/blog/woonbeurs-a-dam-2010/ to http://example.com/404, but it redirects me to http://example.com/404woonbeurs-a-dam-2010/

[image]

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: `/404$1` -> is `$1` supposed to be query parameters? If so, use the `QSA` flag instead. In any case, please provide examples of URIs you're expecting to trigger these rules with.

Comment: Sorry, I just editted my post.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening (that seems pretty weird), but is there a point in capturing what's after the trailing slash (what's bound to `$1`)? What if you just redirect to `/404`?

Comment: That gives me the exact same result :(

Comment: Are your redirect rules in a virtual host config file or in a .htaccess file? If that's the former, are you restarting/reloading config from your webserver? (just in case)

Comment: They are in a .htaccess file on a live server. Sorry, how do I restart/reload config from my webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/?blog/woonbeurs-a-dam-2010/(.*)?$ /404$1 [R,L]
```

**EDIT:**

From the screenshot you provided, I can see you are adding a rewrite rule of the samw path that is overriding the rest rewrites of the same path.

Delete this line from your htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/(.*)?$ /404$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Still no luck. I added a screenshot of my htaccess in my post.

Comment: Yes, thanks alot! It is working. I didn't know that the order of the redirects would matter. Now I am thinking about it, it does make sense. I will rearrange everything now. Thank you